# Live update with Server Sent Events (SSE), ember-data, and Rails 4 backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, ember-data, server-sent-events

I got live updates working with ember and Rails 4 with the help of Railscast #401. ActionController::Live on the backend and EventSource in my Ember code.

The event listener prepends a div with the content sent from the server, but there are 2 problems:

1. The template on my local browser updates automatically, causing 2 duplicate records to display. So I tried to create a temporary client ID and compare ids before prepending to the DOM. This proved to be quite glitchy, plus it doesn't seem like the ember way...
2. I found the ember store 'push' and 'pushPayload' methods but I couldn't get those to update my template either.

Here is the relevant code:

**Method 1 Using DOM prepend** -

```
Auth.NotebookIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(

model: ->
    @modelFor('notebook').get('notes')

activate: ->
    self = @
    source = new EventSource('/api/v1/testposts')
    source.addEventListener 'message', (e) ->
        data = $.parseJSON(e.data)

        unless self.controllerFor('postsNew').get('savedId') is data.id
            $("#allposts").prepend $("<div class=\"post\">").text(data.content)
```

'savedId' is set in the Posts.new controller after a post is saved. This is hit or miss...

**Method 2 Using store.push** -

```
Auth.NotebookIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(

model: ->
    @modelFor('notebook').get('notes')

activate: ->
    self = @
    source = new EventSource('/api/v1/testposts')
    source.addEventListener 'message', (e) ->
        data = $.parseJSON(e.data)
        self.store.push "post",
            id: data.id
            content: data.content
```

The push method does not update the template.

**Method 3 - Works *SOME* of the time**

```
Auth.NotebookIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(

model: ->
    @modelFor('notebook').get('notes')

activate: ->
    self = @
    source = new EventSource('/api/v1/testposts')
    source.addEventListener 'message', (e) ->
        data = $.parseJSON(e.data)

        self.store.find("post", data.id).then (stuff) ->
            console.log('PUSH NEW POST')
            posts = self.modelFor('notebook').get('posts')
            posts.addObject(stuff)
```

When I open up a Chrome and Firefox browser side by side and add new posts, they'll show up only about 60-70% of the time...still looking for where my error might be.

Thanks in advance for any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ember-Data, by adding the object that is sent by the server, the application is able to sync to the server and update the template. This seems clean and it works consistently...but only in Chrome, not in Firefox.

I'm adding it as an answer because it's a step forward for this question, but its not the correct answer yet. Hoping to find something soon.

```
Auth.NotebookIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(

    activate: ->
        self = @
        source = new EventSource('/api/v1/testposts')
        source.onmessage = (e) ->
            console.log('This shows up in Chrome but not in Firefox')
            data = $.parseJSON(e.data)
            self.store.find("post", data.id).then (stuff) ->
                posts = self.modelFor('notebook').get('posts')
                posts.addObject(stuff)
                stuff.save()
```